# How to Set ListView Height Depending on the Items inside ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-scrollview

I'm trying to add `listView` inside `scrollView` and.

the problem is I can't set the `ListView` height programmatically and correctly redraw the `ScrollView`, as the items below it still in the old position before changing the height.

XML

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/movie_detail_scroll_view"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/movie_detail"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipChildren="false">
        ...........
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/trails_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/movie_videos_container"
            android:choiceMode="none"/>
        <include
            android:id="@+id/movie_reviews_container"
            layout="@layout/partial_movie_reviews"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/trails_list_view"/>
        ............
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

the method that I used to resize the listView:

```
/**
 * Sets ListView height dynamically based on the height of the items.
 *
 * @param listView to be resized
 * @return true if the listView is successfully resized, false otherwise
 */
public static boolean setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(ListView listView, ViewGroup container) {

    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter != null) {

        int numberOfItems = listAdapter.getCount();

        // Get total height of all items.
        int totalItemsHeight = 0;
        for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < numberOfItems; itemPos++) {
            View item = listAdapter.getView(itemPos, null, listView);
            item.measure(0, 0);
            totalItemsHeight += item.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        // Get total height of all item dividers.
        int totalDividersHeight = listView.getDividerHeight() * (numberOfItems - 1);

        // Set list height.
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalItemsHeight + totalDividersHeight;
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();

        //redraw the container layout.
        container.requestLayout();

        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

the result:
[image]

I can't get rid of this free space even if when I redraw the `ScrollView`

what should I do?

Comment: Are you sure ListView is the easiest way to do this? LinearLayout might be a quicker solution if the list is very short.

Comment: I will try LinearLayout

Comment: Have you tried modifying the layout_height in ListView?

Comment: Did you got the solution to it? As I am also facing the same problem...??

Comment: No, I switched to recycle view with a horizontal orientation, here is my new layout may be you find it useful.https://github.com/humazed/PopularMovies/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_movie_details.xml

Comment: Try using RecyclerView, it's much more easier for things like this one. Plus ListView is becoming deprecated

Comment: can you please provide the layout of the item in the listview

Comment: post your Full XML of layout and partial_movie_reviews

Comment: @skryshtafovych, unfortunately, this is impossible as this is an old question, I know you want to make sure I set the height as `wrap_content` I'm pretty sure I set it as `wrap_content`

Answer (score 4):

This works 100% for chat, even if the elements' heights differ.

```
public static boolean setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(ListView listView) {

    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter != null) {

        int numberOfItems = listAdapter.getCount();

        // Get total height of all items.
        int totalItemsHeight = 0;
        for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < numberOfItems; itemPos++) {
            View item = listAdapter.getView(itemPos, null, listView);
            float px = 500 * (listView.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
            item.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((int) px, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            totalItemsHeight += item.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        // Get total height of all item dividers.
        int totalDividersHeight = listView.getDividerHeight() *
                (numberOfItems - 1);
        // Get padding
        int totalPadding = listView.getPaddingTop() + listView.getPaddingBottom();

        // Set list height.
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalItemsHeight + totalDividersHeight + totalPadding;
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
        //setDynamicHeight(listView);
        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I use this with custom adapter. Change this parametr  (number 500) = 500 * (listView.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density); for you need.

Comment: but what is 500?

Comment: Change 500 for you need. I use 320. It is working for Lenovo A7000 and Xaomi.

Comment: There is another option that would not make two lists. Make the header in it put everything I need.

Comment: works fine to me even with custom adapter..nice work bro

Comment: I was little bit worried about my project timeline because of this child listview height. Suddenly I found your answer and it works like a charm. Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

Make your scrollview like as follows:

```
<ScrollView
 android:id="@+id/movie_detail_scroll_view"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:fillViewport="true">
```

Comment: the same problem still existing

Answer (score 0):

try listview

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

also dont remove:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

from scrollview

Comment: the same problem still existing

Comment: if I used android:layout_height="wrap_content"
it will only show one item

Comment: even if I removed android:fillViewport="true"
and please add your edits in comments and only edit the answer when it works to make it easy for me to see your message.

Answer (score 0):

change to linear

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/movie_detail"
            style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:clipChildren="false">
                     ...........
             <ListView
                android:id="@+id/trails_list_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/movie_videos_container"
                android:choiceMode="none"/>
            <include
                android:id="@+id/movie_reviews_container"
                layout="@layout/partial_movie_reviews"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
                  ............
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommended to use `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`

**1. ListView**

Use NestedScrollview instead of Scrollview

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
```

replace fix height to `wrap_content`
`android:layout_height="200dp"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

calculate dynamic height of listview

```
public void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        // pre-condition
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = listView.getPaddingTop() + listView.getPaddingBottom();
    int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);

        if(listItem != null){
            // This next line is needed before you call measure or else you won't get measured height at all. The listitem needs to be drawn first to know the height.
            listItem.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            listItem.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();

        }
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

**2. RecyclerView**

```
public class MaxHeightRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    private int mMaxHeight;

    public MaxHeightRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MaxHeightRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize(context, attrs);
    }

    public MaxHeightRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initialize(context, attrs);
    }

    private void initialize(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray arr = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MaxHeightScrollView);
        mMaxHeight = arr.getLayoutDimension(R.styleable.MaxHeightScrollView_maxHeight, mMaxHeight);
        arr.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if (mMaxHeight > 0) {
            heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mMaxHeight, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        }
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

in attrs.xml

```
<declare-styleable name="MaxHeightScrollView">
        <attr name="maxHeight" format="dimension" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

then set `maxHeight = 200dp` in xml
if height is less then 200dp then it will take `wrap_content` and after 200dp it will scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Take those listview or RecyclerView in a Constraint Layout.. Then no need of Scrollview view .. and also not worrying about list HEIGHTs...